# The loadImageInfo(Context context, Uri uri) API failed to be called

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

When integrating HUAWEI Panorama Kit into my app, I tried calling the **loadImageInfo** method to load a panorama, but failed. I checked the image format and size, and found that both of them meet the requirements. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input parameters are correct, the possible cause is that the input image does not carry the correct GPano-compliant XMP metadata. You can use PendingResult loadImageInfo(Context context, Uri uri, int type) to specify the image type for forcible redirection.